# PHP+FFMPEG add music to video alternative?

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I create the code using php+ffmpeg to add music to video.
this code works fine but
My cpu usage 100% when it execute.
Is any other alternative for this??
any alternetive to ffmpeg??

```
<?php
shell_exec("ffmpeg -i video.avi -i audio.mp3 -map 0 -map 1 -codec copy -shortest output_video.avi")
?>
```

Comment: See [nice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nice_%28Unix%29). It can set the priority of the process (although a low priority process can still reach 99% CPU usage depending on available resources).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FFMpeg performs the conversion as fast as possible, and that indeed means 100% CPU usage (assuming a single CPU).

The only way in FFMpeg to slow down encoding is to use the `-re` option that tells the decoder to read the input file at its native framerate.

So in your case, you should try:

```
ffmpeg -re -i video.avi -i audio.mp3 -map 0 -map 1 -codec copy -shortest output_video.avi
```

By doing so, the encoding operation will take as long as the duration of your input file, and CPU usage will be much lower.